# Selecionar valores diferentes em duas tabelas - SQL e PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Tenho duas tabelas a **pedido_tb** e a **pedido_grade**, o que eu quero fazer é comparar, os valores da coluna "**pedido**" da tabela pedido_tb e da coluna "**n_pedido**" da pedido_grade, basicamente, gostaria de obter os valores que tem na pedido_tb e não tem na pedido_grade.

Tentei o seguinte código:

```
$sql = "SELECT pedido FROM pedido_tb WHERE pedido NOT IN (SELECT n_pedido FROM pedido_grade)";

$disp_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);

$num = $disp_sql->num_rows;

echo "</br>número de linhas ".$num."</br>";
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do por que não retorna nada?

Comment: A query aparentemente está correta. fiz uma resposta a sua pergunta usando LEFT JOIN, se não funcionar verifique se seus erros no php não estão desabilitados, pode haver algum erro de conexão ou apontando para uma base errada. tem n possibilidades.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT pedido FROM table1 WHERE pedido NOT IN (SELECT n_pedido FROM table2)
```

Comment: Olá Rodrigo, eu editei minha pergunta pois não funcionou o código :/

Answer (score 2):

Basta fazer um simples `SELECT` com `subquery`

```
SELECT pedido FROM table1 WHERE pedido NOT IN (SELECT n_pedido FROM table2)
```

Porém, caso necessite um dia exibir registros das duas tabelas pode utilizar `JOIN`, portanto, vou deixar um exemplo para você estudar

**INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT pedido.table, n_pedido.table2 FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

**LEFT OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT pedido.table, n_pedido.table2 FROM table1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: obrigado por responder @Victor, vi que na sua comparação table1.id = table2.id, as duas colunas tem o mesmo nome, e se forem de nomes diferentes, também funcionária? obrigado

Comment: eu dei um exemplo para você que a comparação é o id, portanto as duas tabelas tem que ter a coluna id, mas se você indicar por exemplo, imagine que a tabela 1 possui um campo produto e a tabela 2 tem um campo id_produto logo,  table1.produto = table2.id_produto dará certo neste caso

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma consulta com LEFT JOIN e faça 1 WHERE onde a coluna da tabela da esquerda seja null, ai retornará apenas os pedidos que não tem pedido grade:

```
SELECT
    p.*
FROM pedido p
LEFT JOIN pedido_grade pg
ON p.pedido = pg.n_pedido
WHERE pg.n_pedido IS NULL;
```